# Separate labels / Summarize conditions with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label, data-visualization

I created a simple plot with Ggplot for two experiments (condition 1, condition 2), where in each experiment I had one "low" and one "high" condition.

Here is an example plot:

```
da<-data.frame(group=c("condition1_high","condition1_low","condition2_high","condition2_low"),numb=c(30,25,26,20))

da %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=group, y=numb, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("grey20","grey80"), ceiling(length(da$group)/2))[1:length(da$group)])
```

Leading to this:
[image: R Plot]

Now I want to separate the labels in a way that the "fill" dimension only includes the labels "low" and "high" on the right and the x-axis summarizes each condition, like this:

[image: Target Plot]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
library(tidyverse)
library("stringi")
da.new <- da %>% separate(group, c("A", "B"), remove = F)

da.new %>% 
mutate_if(is.character, stri_trans_totitle) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=A, y=numb, fill = B)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("grey20","grey80"), ceiling(length(da.new$A)/2))[1:length(da.new$A)],
                    name = "Group") +
  labs(x="Experimental Condition") +
  geom_text(aes(label=numb), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in general, that works fine.

In my original code, I have one more line to add the y-values as text over the bars. This doesn't work anymore after implementing your approach:


  geom_text(aes(label=numb, vjust=-1))